# Size of pointer, pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

How can I justify the output of the below C program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *c[] = {"Mahesh", "Ganesh", "999", "333"};
char *a;
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp = cp;

int main(void) {
    printf("%d %d %d %d ",sizeof(a),sizeof(c),sizeof(cp),sizeof(cpp));
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
4 16 16 4
```

Why?

[Here is the ideone link](https://ideone.com/QAetFj) if you want to fiddle with it.

Comment: `c` and `cp` are arrays, `a` and `cpp` are not. The real question is what other result did you expect?

Comment: You're using the wrong format specifier. `size_t` is `%zu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *c[] = {"Mahesh", "Ganesh", "999", "333"};
```

`c` is an array of `char*` pointers.  The initializer gives it a length of 4 elements, so it's of type `char *[4]`.  The size of that type, and therefore of `c`, is `4 * sizeof (char*)`.

```
char *a;
```

`a` is a pointer of type `char*`.

```
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
```

`cp` is an array of `char**` pointers.  The initializer has 4 elements, so it's of type `char **[4]`.  It size is `4 * sizeof (char**)`.

```
char ***cpp = cp;
```

`cpp` is a pointer to pointer to pointer to `char`, or `char***`.  Its size is `sizeof (char***)`.

Your code uses `%d` to print the size values.  This is incorrect -- but it happens to work on your system.  Probably `int` and `size_t` are the same size.  To print a `size_t` value correctly, use `%zu` -- or, if the value isn't very large, you can cast it to `int` and use `%d`.  (The `%zu` format was introduced in C99; there might still be some implementations that don't support it.)

The particular sizes you get:

```
sizeof a == 4
sizeof c == 16
sizeof cp == 16
sizeof cpp == 4
```

are specific to your system.  Apparently your system uses 4-byte pointers. Other systems may have pointers of different sizes; 8 bytes is common. Almost all systems use the same size for all pointer types, but that's not guaranteed; it's possible, for example, for `char*` to be larger than `char***`. (Some systems might require more information to specify a byte location in memory than a word location.)

(You'll note that I omitted the parentheses on the `sizeof` expressions. That's legal because `sizeof` is an operator, not a function; its operand is either an expression (which may or may not be parenthesized) or a type  name in parentheses, like `sizeof (char*)`.)

Answer (score 3):

`a` is an usually pointer,  which represents the memory address. On 32-bit operating system, 32bit (4 Byte) unsigned integer is used to represent the address. Therefore, `sizeof(a)` is `4`.

`c` is an array with 4 element, each element is a pointer, its size is `4*4 = 16`

`cp` is also an array, each element is a pointer (the first `*`, wich point to another pointer (the second `*`). The later pointer points to an string in the memory. Therefore its basic element size should represent the size of a pointer. and then  `sizeof(cp) = 4*4 = 16`.

`cpp` is a pointer's pointer's pointer. It is as well represent the 32bit memory address. therefore its `sizeof` is also `4`.

Comment: hmmm... a bit more clear. Main confusion is with `**cp[]`. I interpreted it as pointer (first `*`) to pointer (second `*`) which points to array (`[]`). And since its pointer to pointer, it must be 4, but its not as you say. Please explain that more, especially *which points to an pointer points to an string*

Comment: Your first paragraph still says that pointers are represented as 32-bit unsigned integers. They might have similar representations, but as far as the language is concerned pointers are not integers, and are neither signed nor unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

**a** is a pointer. **cpp** is also a pointer just to different type (pointer to pointer to pointer).
Now **c** is an array. You have 4 elements, each is a pointer so you have 4 * 4 = 16 (it would be different if you would run it on x64).
Similar goes for **cp**. Try changing type to int and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you got 4 16 16 4, is because 'a' is simply a pointer, on its own, which only requires 4 bytes (as a pointer is holding a 32bit address depending on your architecture) and so when you have a **pointer which is == to a *pointer[], your really making an array of pointers, and since you initalized 4 things that created 4 pointers, thus the 4x4 = 16. And for the cpp you may ask "well wouldn't it then be 16 as it was initalized?" and the answer is no, because a ***pointer is its own separate variable and still just a pointer(a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, or a pointer to an array of pointers), and requires only 4bytes of memory.